# Jquery selector - (beginner)

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I tried to use the jquery selector but it fails.

Demo:
http://jsbin.com/vozufura/2/edit

HTML

```
 <div id="menu-123"></div>
 <div id="menu-456"></div>
 <div id="test" ></div>
```

CSS

```
div {
height: 50px;
width: 100px;
background: red;
}
```

Javascript

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('[id^="menu_"]').css("background", "black");
 });
```

The first 2 division should change its background to black. But it doesn't.

Comment: You did '_' instead of '-'.

Comment: Classic case of 'itchy shift finger'

Comment: Changed. No it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use `menu-` instead of `menu_`,

```
$('[id^="menu-"]').css("background", "black");
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9ASbH/)

---

Other suggestion, You can use **class** for this purpose.

HTML:

```
 <div id="menu-123" class="hai"></div>
 <div id="menu-456"  class="hai"></div>
 <div id="test" ></div>
```

JS:

```
$('.hai').css("background", "black");
```

Comment: @WileyNg See the demo, i just added it for you.

Comment: Yes. But actually I am exploring regular expressions in jquery and I just want to select "menu-123" and "menu-456". The codes I tried.

Comment: @WileyNg: JQuery doesn't support regular expression selectors. Though I believe there are plugins available that add regex functionality

Comment: So it appears that JQuery doesn't support regular expression selectors

Answer (score 0):

**JQuery doesn't support regular expression selectors.**

Try with `menu` or `menu-`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('[id^="menu"]').css("background", "black");
});
```